# this.Region Path data leads to a tiny window

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, svg

So I created a simple form to test out using an SVG image to draw a custom shaped window. [Inspiration found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-shaped-windows-form)

It seems to work fine, but no matter what I do my window size is too small to put any controls on.

Reasons for doing this:  It's cool?  Windows needs better themeing support.  I was bored!

I am using Svg from nuget.com from within Visual Studio

Code:

```
    using Svg;

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1; public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    internal class NativeMethods
    {
        // Allows forms with Toolbox property set to false to be moved
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath frmshp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        //frmshp.AddEllipse(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        //SvgDocument.Open(@"TestWindowsshape.svg");
        SvgDocument newshp = SvgDocument.Open(@"TestWindowsshape.svg");
        frmshp = (newshp.Path);

        this.Region = new Region(frmshp);
    }
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make settings window movable without a titlebar
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            NativeMethods.ReleaseCapture();
            NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN (IntPtr)HT_CAPTION, (IntPtr)0);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to increase the svg size, played with the code some, but nothing I do will make the drawn window bigger.  I know I can do this with a BMP, and the TransparancyKey option, but I would like to not do it that way, since the BMP & transparency method has the drawback of not being able to use one color in the bitmap itself.  Any advice would be appreciated

Edit:

```
   Matrix m = new Matrix();
   m.Scale(100, 100, MatrixOrder.Append);
   m.Translate(100, 100, MatrixOrder.Append);
   newshp.Path.Transform(m);
```

Has been tried, with no effect. I would assume that this should have worked does that mean the problem is within my SVG?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the SVG file, i adjusted the size of a Rectangle in Notepad++ and got a bigger windows, however more complex shapes will be a hassle.  It seems Inkscape cannot create SVGs of a reliable size... I have the "Document properties" set to my screen resolution, but the vectors all turn out too small. Perhaps Illustrator can do this properly.